# How to run a .exe file using php with a press of a button from html frontend

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

Im having hard time to make this work,

This is my javascript function:

```
  function OpenINO()
  {
  var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","Arduino/RIKDuino/opentoide.php",true);
  }
```

and my opentoide.php file :

```
 <?php 
 exec('RIKDuino.ino')
 ?>
```

i even tried:

```
  <?php 
  exec('C:\[myfilepath]\RIKDuino.ino')
  ?>
```

the .ino is asociated with arduino.exe and this file is inside the .php file too. i cant seem to run the .ino file but it runs when i open it using cmd,

im not sure if its the xmlrequest is wrong or something really is wrong, can someone please help me?

Comment: What's the output of exec()? Shouldn't your `xmlhttp.open` be inside the if statement to check if page is ready and 200 status? Any PHP errors? Does it work if you visit `opentoide.php` manually

Comment: it worked when i opened the opentoide.php, however if i clicked the button that is supposed do that .php command it doesnt work...

Comment: Open dev tools and look at console. Is there any output from the javascript?

Comment: nope, nothings popping out if i click the button

Comment: So I can do my own tests with how your `OpenINO` is working, could you please also provide the HTML that calls that function?

Comment: From first look; you're calling `OpenINOTest()` but the method is called `OpenINO()` ?

Comment: <button class = "button" onclick = "OpenINO" ><span>Open IDE</span></button>

Comment: sorry, thats supposed to be OpenINO not OpenINOTest, i was testing stuffs so i edited it, yes, logically it should work, however it wont

Comment: *facepalm* fixed it... demn xmlhttp request...

Answer (score 1):

*facepalm* fixed it... demn xmlhttp request... Thank you so much for your help @IsThisJavascript i was missing a xmlhttp.send on the script.. thank you so much for your help

heres the final code for the script if someone needs it someday,

```
function OpenINOTest()
{


var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    }
}
   xmlhttp.open("POST","Arduino/RIKDuino/opentoide.php",true);
   alert('Code Uploaded to IDE, Ide Will start Soon.')
   xmlhttp.send("fowk");
}
```

Comment: I didn't help much but happy to hear it's sorted :)